# (React) How to send variable value to other component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

It's a nice day.

```
//App.js 
 
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, createContext, useContext } from "react"
import { 
  StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, Linking, Button,
  SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
 

export default function App() {
  const wannaConst = 'qwqw'
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        Good Good
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
```

```
//screens > Home > Home.js

import React from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{wannaConst}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home
```

I wanna use App.js's wannaConst's Variable Value
at screens > Home > Home.js

if wannaConst = 'qrqr',
Home components return [qrqr] screens.

or wannaConst = 'help me :(',
Home components return [help me :(] screens...
and so on.

How to solve it? use Redux? or ContextAPI?
Thx for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both way will work OK. If your project is small or middle-sized, context API will work without any problem.

**AppContext.jsx**

```
import {createContext} from 'react';
export default createContext({
  wannaConst: 'qwqw'
}); // provide initial value
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState, createContext, useContext, useCallback } from "react"
import { 
  StyleSheet, StatusBar, View, Text, Linking, Button,
  SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
import AppContext from './AppContext'

export default function App() {

  // You can manage AppContext state here
  const [contextValue, setContextValue] = useState({
    wannaConst: 'qrqr' // provide initial value here, default value in AppContext.jsx will be overwritten
  }};

  // context values are also React states. You can update the state like any other React states
  const handlePressButton = useCallback(
    () => setContextValue({wannaConst: 'good good'}), 
  []);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <View>
        <Text>
          Good Good
        </Text>
        <Button onPress={handlePressButton}>
           Change context to 'good good'
        </Button>
      </View>
      //... child components that are going to consume AppContext value
    </AppContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Be aware that `screens/Home/Home.js` should be nested inside `AppContext.Provider`. Most of the case, it will be like so, because you will create [stack/tab navigations](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) and list all the navigation routes and screens under `App.jsx`.

**Home.jsx**

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import AppContext from './AppContext';

const Home = () => {
  const appContext = useContext(AppContext);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{appContext.wannaConst}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Using redux is somewhat difficult but it is almost mandatory in enterprise apps. Here you can find a good [source](https://react.vlpt.us/) for modern react and redux